# Every time I open the terminal, it SAYS

Tags: command-line, directory, anaconda

```
bash: path-to-mcu-package: No such file or directory
```

I tried checking with,

```
source ~/.bashrc
bash: path-to-mcu-package: No such file or directory
```

Although,when I do `cd ~ && ls -la`, I see `-rw-r--r--  1 pc_230 pc_230  4301 Feb  3 16:20 .bashrc`

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

nano ~/.bashrc

remove the line that contains path-to-mcu-package or correct it to have the proper path set to it.